# Confidence interval for Binomial Distribution

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, binomial-distribution, confidence-interval

I have recently heard that when constructing confidence intervals for a binomial distribution, with small probability of a success, and a large sample size it is best to use a Poisson distribution. I am trying to verify a theoretical result with a simulation. My theo probability is 0.00008539, and after 26,000,000 simulations it reported 2,233 successes (giving sample success probability 0.00008588). The theoretical number of successes is 2220.2. I understand the 95% confidence interval is $\lambda \pm 1.96\sqrt{\lambda/n}$, but in determining if my sim is working correctly, I am not sure when/where to use the sample $\lambda$ ($\hat{\lambda}$?) vs the theoretical $\lambda$. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

If you are already using a normal (Wald) approximation for the confidence interval (as evidenced by the use of $1.96$) then there is no benefit to using the Poisson approximation.  You would just have $$n = 26 \times 10^6, \quad X = 2233, \quad \hat p = \frac{X}{n}, \tag{1}$$ and your $100(1-\alpha)\%$ Wald confidence interval is

$$\hat p \pm z_{\alpha/2}^* \sqrt{\frac{\hat p(1-\hat p)}{n}}. \tag{2}$$  This gives a margin of error of $3.56205 \times 10^{-6}$ and the resulting $95\%$ Wald confidence interval is $$(8.23226, 8.94467) \times 10^{-5}. \tag{3}$$

Notice that the Poisson model would have $\hat \lambda = n \hat p = X$, thus the interval $(2)$ becomes
$$\frac{1}{n} \left( n \hat p \pm z_{\alpha/2}^* \sqrt{n\hat p(1-\hat p)} \right) = \frac{1}{n} \left( \hat \lambda \pm z_{\alpha/2}^* \sqrt{\hat \lambda (1 - \hat p)} \right). \tag{4}$$  When $\hat p \approx 0$, this becomes the Poisson interval with $1$ observation, scaled by the sample size.

By comparison, the $95\%$ [Wilson score interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval#Wilson_score_interval) is
$$(8.23957, 8.95213) \times 10^{-5} \tag{5}$$ and the exact $95\%$ [(Clopper-Pearson) interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval#Clopper%E2%80%93Pearson_interval) is
$$(8.23591, 8.95222) \times 10^{-5}. \tag{6}$$  The interval $(6)$ is exact in the sense that it is guaranteed to have at least the nominal coverage probability.

Comment: Thank you for the response. So using your (4) I believe I have the following values: $n=26,000,000, \hat{\lambda}=2233, \hat{p}=0.000089958, z_{\alpha/2}=2.241$ giving interval $(8.1811,8.9958)*10^{-5}$, this interval seems quite a bit different, so I am guessing I made a mistake with my $z_{\alpha/2}$?

Comment: @TextureClip the choice of critical value depends on the desired confidence level.  For $\alpha = 0.05$ corresponding to a $95\%$ confidence interval, $z_{\alpha/2}^* \approx 1.96$.  Your choice appears to correspond to $\alpha = 0.025$ for a confidence level of $97.5\%$.  The reason why I say "you are already using a normal approximation...(as evidenced by the use of 1.96)" is not to suggest the choice of $1.96$ is wrong, but rather, to point out that $z_{\alpha/2}^*$ is a critical value of a normal distribution, hence the interval estimate is based on a normal approximation.

Comment: To clarify, I define $z_{\alpha/2}^*$ to mean the value satisfying $$\Pr[Z > z_{\alpha/2}^*] = \alpha/2,$$ the upper $\alpha/2$ quantile of the standard normal distribution.  similarly, $z_{\alpha/2}$ (no star) satisfies $$\Pr[Z \le z_{\alpha/2}] = \alpha/2,$$ the lower $\alpha/2$ quantile.

Comment: Ok, I believe I found my mistake, my $z_{alpha/2}$ should be 1.96. This gives me intervals of $(8.2323,8.9447)*10^{-5}$ using (4). How does one decide which interval to use between 4/5/6?

Comment: @TextureClip I do not recommend $(4)$, the Wald interval, for reasons described in the Wikipedia article in the links provided in my main answer.  The Wilson score interval $(5)$ is my preferred choice in most cases; however, in certain situations, the exact interval $(6)$ is recommended (e.g., for reporting to regulatory agencies).  The problem with the exact interval is that it can be overly conservative--however, in this case, with a very large sample size, the coverage probability is very close to the nominal.  In summary I would accept $(5)$ or $(6)$ in practice.

Answer (score 1):

The Poisson approximation to the Binomial is that for $p$ small and $n$ large,

$$\mathrm{Bin}(n, p) \approx \mathrm{Pois}(np);$$

in other words, we're trying to find $\lambda = np$, and your estimate $\hat \lambda = 2233$ is the number of observed successes.

The $n$ in your confidence interval is a different value (not to be confused with the first $n$); this is just the number of times you observed a Poisson, which in your case is 1. So you would get the confidence interval $\hat \lambda \pm 1.96 \sqrt{\hat\lambda}$ for $\lambda$, and dividing that by $n=26\cdot10^6$ gives your confidence interval for $p$.

By my numbers, I think you should end up with the confidence interval $0.00008588 \pm 0.00000356$, which easily contains your theoretical estimate.